# First argument of Snackbar.make() method in Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm new to Material Design. While i was searching about displaying a snackbar, i see there are two different ways of doing it :

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout,...
}}
new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view,...
}}
```

Both of two works perfectly. I didn't understand why? I think view refers to Button object and mCoordinatorLayout refers to CoordinatorLayout object. They are different object but either of two can be given as first argument to Snackbar.make( ) method. Why?

Full source code is as following:

main layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/showSnackbarButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/show_snackbar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCoordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

    mShowSnackbarButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showSnackbarButton);
    mShowSnackbarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout,
                    "This is a simple Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // Custom action
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"this is a toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple.

If you have a look at the sourcecode for the `Snackbar` you'll see that when making the `Snackbar` there's a call to a private method called `findSuitableParent` which takes a `View` (the view you give it) and continues to loop through the view hierarchy until it either finds a `CoordinatorLayout` or the `contentView`, which is the view that holds everything in your screen.

See: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.java#133

Where the [findSuitableParent(View view)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.java#173) is called from.

I found out about this when forking the code for a project where I had to move the `Snackbar` from the bottom to the top of the screen ;-)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the CoordinatorLayout directly it will avoid "going up" in the hierarchy to find a CoordinatorLayout. So you save some computation from being done.

If you use a View it will try to find a CoordinatorLayout or fallback on the the window decor's content view.

This is the method in Snackbar that is used to find a "suitable parent":

```
private static ViewGroup findSuitableParent(View view) {
    ViewGroup fallback = null;
    do {
        if (view instanceof CoordinatorLayout) {
            // We've found a CoordinatorLayout, use it
            return (ViewGroup) view;
        } else if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
            if (view.getId() == android.R.id.content) {
                // If we've hit the decor content view, then we didn't find a CoL in the
                // hierarchy, so use it.
                return (ViewGroup) view;
            } else {
                // It's not the content view but we'll use it as our fallback
                fallback = (ViewGroup) view;
            }
        }

        if (view != null) {
            // Else, we will loop and crawl up the view hierarchy and try to find a parent
            final ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
            view = parent instanceof View ? (View) parent : null;
        }
    } while (view != null);

    // If we reach here then we didn't find a CoL or a suitable content view so we'll fallback
    return fallback;
}
```